# Access api which is using google oauth2

Tags: python, curl, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Hey I am using server that is configured with google oauth2 Now when I try get URIs from browser I get desired response but when try to do same with curl or python I get no response, wondering whats missing here and what headers should I have to add in curl request

`curl -X GET "http://service.mydomain.com//application"`

this url is api endpoint of `spinnaker` which reponse to get and post methods. Because in my browser I am logged in with gmail account it allows me to make such request. But when using curl I get no response.

spinnaker api refrence: https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/api/docs.html

Refrence is showing curl -X methods not header or authentication part which is required to allow curl request to get data from spinnaker api.

Comment: beyond the fact that you have two / before application its going to be hard to help you without knowing exactly what your application is doing.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for your input I edit question description hope it is clear now.

Comment: You will need the `Access Token` from the OAuth flow. Then you add this as a header to curl: `Authorization: Bearer <replace_with_access_token>`.  Your $99 question is how to get the access token from your application or the web browser. I wrote this article on OAuth and Curl: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl/